# Select touching/joined vertices/edges/faces

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools

Is there any way to select touching/joined vertices/edges/faces in edit mode?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are several ways:

- Select at least one element (face/vert/etc.) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to *Select Linked*.
- Press <kbd>L</kbd> while hovering over an element with the mouse to select all elements connected to that element.
- Select at least one element and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> to *Grow* the selection until everything is selected.
- Select at least one face and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to select connected faces which have the same or similar normal/direction.

If you meant you want to select **all** elements that are connected to other elements, create/select a single vertex and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>*> Amount of connecting edges* (if you want don't want to select edges that don't connect to faces, use *Amount of adjacent faces* instead), then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to invert the selection.

See [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/modeling/meshes/selecting/index.html#selecting) for a full list and description of all selection tools.

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-Alt-F worked perfectly for me. I had to set the Sharpness parameter to 2 degrees as my faces weren't quite colinear. Saved me a ton of pain - thanks!

Comment: +1 for Ctrl+Numpad, most underrated shortcut ever

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>B</kbd> for border select, or <kbd>C</kbd> for circle select, or hold and drag <kbd>LMB</kbd> while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to make a lasso select.

**P.S.:** For overlapped elements (if it is what you mean), It should be done in **Wireframe** display mode, or toggle off the *Limit selection to visible* button on the 3D View header.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for what I wanted to do. Cheers!