# How do you do an island select?

Tags: selection-tools

According [to this video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FIfwMEDMGz8&t=3m18s), on blender 2.71 to select just one of two objects that have previously been joined (with <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>), you hover your mouse over the object, and press <kbd>L</kbd>. ( Thats a lowercase <kbd>L</kbd> )

However, this does not do an island select, but instead pops up a menu, none of which do what is expected.

How do you do an island select on blender 2.7x?

[image]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6679/599

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have joined the two objects, they are now one object. In order to edit/select the geometry of an object, you must be in *[edit mode](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes)*.

You can press <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> to toggle edit mode, or set the mode via the selector in *3D view > header*:

[image]

Once in edit mode, <kbd>L</kbd> works as expected:

[image]

Note that you can also select geometry connected the selected geometry with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>:

[image]