# One object, lots of materials

Tags: modeling, materials

I made a stone cabin in blender but I forgot to set materials to different parts of it and I joined it all together.

Is there a way to set materials to loose parts or do I have to separate it (which would give me about 300 loose parts)?

If there isn't, can I somehow separate loose parts one by one (so that I can separate for example all parts of roof and rejoin them separately)?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/16075/599

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can separate mesh in editmode with <kbd>P</kbd>. You get some options to choose, I think they are self-explanatory:

[image]

To select specific loose part select any of its vertices and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

You can also add multiple materials to object and each apply to specific faces:

[image]

Make selection and in edit-mode hit *Assign*. The first material slot will be the default one.