# Selecting - how to differentiate "elements"?

Tags: selection-tools

In the attached test_bag.blend file, the bag has several parts: front, back, base, etc. How does one select an individual "part" of the bag without selecting others?
For example, select only the front or back or interior part.

Further, I would appreciate a link to, or in depth tutorial of, selecting/selections; -- beyond the basic tutorials on utube, et.al.
TIA

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3504807/test_bag.blend1

Comment: you can start by reading:  http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Selecting and http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Selecting

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6679/599

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways in *edit mode* (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>):

- Press <kbd>L</kbd> while hovering the mouse over the part of the bag you want to select. This will select all the geometry which is connected to the part under your cursor.
- Select some geometry (e.g. with <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>), then press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>. This will select all the geometry which is connected to the existing selection.

If you want to separate the parts into separate *objects*, then press <kbd>P</kbd>*> Loose parts* in edit mode. This will separate disconnected parts of the object into their own objects.

Answer (score 1):

You should first remove any duplicated vertices *Edit Mode / Tools-Tab - Remove Doubles*.

Selecting all <kbd>A</kbd> and separating <kbd>P</kbd> *Loose parts* would lead to something like:

[image]

If you want to select front and back switch to front view orthographic view <kbd>Numpad-1</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad-5</kbd> and use Box select <kbd>B</kbd>, make sure that limit selection to visible is enabled (highlighted icon in the last image)

Assign the selection to vertex group, this enables you to select them later e.g.

[image]

repeat that for all groups you need in the appropriate view (the bottom is easier selected by the 'select linked' method gandalf3 has already described).

[image]

Comment: I do not see that icon. Where is this located in Blender 2.82?