# Removing Mesh Parts

Tags: mesh

I'm 100% new to blender, but managed to finally get the object imported and to a point where I could see it.  I want to try and remove the hose assembly from the main tank.  I guess there isn't a giant eraser tool, so what would be the best way?
[image: Tank and Hose]

Comment: Mouse over the hose, then press "L".  The hose should select, then press "X" and choose delete.

Comment: Modeling in Blender in particular doesn't assume eraser for deleting unneeded stuff, you need to select geometry itself (because those are the objects which actually exist in 3d space). You might want to learn about different ways of [selecting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html) and organizing meshes as object components

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17728/selecting-how-to-differentiate-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---- I highly recommend you watch some general tutorials to get an understanding ----

However, for this specific model it appears like the hose is not part of the drum geometry. You can select any point on it and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to select all linked. Then you can use delete (<kbd>X</kbd>) to get rid of the hose.